# Probability of two vectors lying in the same orthant

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, asymptotics, euclidean-geometry

Let $S^{d-1} = \{x \in \mathbb R^d: \|x\| = 1\}$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d$. Let $v$, $w$ be drawn uniformly at random from $S^{d-1}$, conditioned on their inner product being equal to $\langle v, w \rangle = \cos \theta$. In other words, $v$ and $w$ have a fixed common angle $\theta$. I am interested in the probability that these two vectors lie in the same orthant, say the all-positive orthant, averaged over all possible $v$ and $w$:
$$f_d(\theta) = \Pr(v > 0 \mid w > 0, \ \langle v, w \rangle = \cos \theta).$$
Here $v > 0$ means that all $d$ coordinates of $v$ are positive.

In particular, I am interested in the asymptotics of large $d \to \infty$ of $f_d(\theta)$ for $\theta \in (0, \frac{1}{2} \pi)$. Equivalently, as $f_d$ scales exponentially in $d$, I'm interested in the function
$$g(\theta) = \lim_{d \to \infty} f_d(\theta)^{1/d}.$$

Note that an approximation to the above probabilities can be obtained by replacing the uniform distribution over the sphere by a multivariate Gaussian distribution, where each coordinate is independently drawn from a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{d})$. For large $d$, with overwhelming probability such a random vector will have norm $1 \pm o(1)$, and with overwhelming probability two such random vectors will have inner product $o(1)$. If we ignore the fact that the norms of such vectors may not exactly be equal to $1$ and that two random vectors may not be exactly orthogonal (which is why this is only an approximation), then two vectors $v$ and $w$ from the sphere with angle $\theta$ can be generated by taking $v = n_1$ and $w = (\cos \theta) n_1 + (\sin \theta) n_2$ for two independent random Gaussian vectors $n_1, n_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{d})^d$. These lie on the sphere exactly if $n_1, n_2$ have norm $1$, and their angle is then equal to $\theta$ if and only if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are orthogonal.

With this approximation, probabilities can be computed quite easily, as different coordinates are independent and probabilities multiply. However, I'm looking for more precise estimates than using this Gaussian approximation of the uniform distribution on the sphere.

So far I've tried sharing this problem with a few others in the department, and rewriting the probability to computing the expected volume of the intersection of the sphere with $d$ orthogonal hyperplanes, but so far nothing led anywhere. Any pointers on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update**: To verify/compare different approaches, simulations for $\theta = \arccos 0.9$ in dimensions $d \in \{10, \dots, 40\}$ show the following trends for $\ln f$:

[image]

The points are the simulation results (using 100.000-500.000 experiments each, so that the number of successes was at least a few hundred) and the line is the linear fit $-0.0133857 - 0.170074 d$, or equivalently $f(\arccos 0.9) \approx C \cdot 0.8436^d$ for a constant $C \approx 1$. This suggests that $g(\arccos 0.9) \approx 0.8436$. The answers given so far say:

- Carlo's answer: $0.66$
- Other answer (main): $1.08$
- Other answer (alternative): $0.71$

So perhaps all answers so far are still far off when $\theta$ is small and the inner product between $v$ and $w$ is large.

Comment: I would have guessed that the gaussian approximation is quite accurate. Are you sure it isn't?

Comment: Indeed, since $(g_i/\sqrt{\sum g_i^2})_{i=1}^d$ with $g_i$ iid standard Gaussian is uniformly distributed on the sphere, the Gaussian computation is not an approximation but rather an exact computation.

Comment: @Brendan: The problem is that without normalization, it is only an approximation as the norms are only $1 + o(1)$ with high probability, rather than exactly $1$. I cannot prove that asymptotically there is a gap between reality and using Gaussian approximations without normalization though so maybe the gap is "negligible" in the limit for large $d$. (My intuition tells me that there should be a small gap though.)

Comment: @ofer: Indeed, using $(g_i/\sqrt{\sum g_i^2})_{i=1}^d$ would be exact, but then the coordinates are no longer independent and I would not know how you'd compute the probabilities anymore. By the approximation above I was referring to simply using $g_i$ for the $i$th coordinate and arguing that the norm will already be close to $1$, in which case coordinates are independent and probabilities multiply. If you have an idea how to compute these probabilities with normalization (using $(g_i/\sqrt{\sum g_i^2})_{i=1}^d$), I'd be interested to know!

Comment: Yes, I would expect the approximation to be good when the angle is small but to gradually get worse as the angle approaches $\pi/2$. Another (equivalent?) approach is to consider two independent vectors with iid components from |N(0,1)|; then you have two random directions in the positive orthant. The inner product satisfies an obvious CLT, which together with concentration of the length should give the right answer if the angle is not far from its expectation. But I don't see how to accurately condition on the length far from the expected angle.

Comment: In the region where the angle is large I do not think there is a problem - the norm concentrates quickly (exponential in $d$ probability of mismatch) while large angle is the typical behavior. In general, you can write down the join LDP for the norm, the angle and $\sum U(g_i)$ where $U$ approximates a function that is $0$ on $R_+$ and $-\infty$ on $R_-$ - these are linear statistics in independent variables and a joint LDP follows I believe from Cramer's theorem.

Comment: @Brendan: If the components are $|N(0,1)|$, then we are talking about a completely different distribution, no? I'm looking for the probability that two vectors lie in the same orthant, given the angle; not the distribution of the angles, given that they lie in the same orthant. (That they lie in the same orthant is not known, and the probability of this event is exactly what I'd like to compute.)

Comment: $f_2(\theta)$ seems easy, and, for $d\ge3$, $f_d(\theta)$ the problem becomes "more geometric" as to what possible configurations one could get of two vectors in the same orthant. For $d=2$ and $\theta=\dfrac\pi3$ if I understand the problem correctly it seems that $f_2(\dfrac\pi3)=\dfrac13$ ... I just thought I am not sure of the question, if the version with "lie in the same orthant" is supposed to have the same answer as the version with "lie in the all-positive orthant".

Comment: This is a nice question!  One might even ask:  what is the joint distribution of <x,y> against the Hamming distance between the sign vector of x and the sign vector of y?  Your question then asks about Pr(Hamming dist = 0 | <x,y> = theta) in this distribution.

Comment: @Mirko: Indeed, for $d = 2$ this is still pretty straightforward and I think the answer was $1 - \frac{2 \theta}{\pi}$. Replacing the orthogonal hyperplanes generated by the canonical basis by two random hyperplanes (and asking the probability that two vectors lie in the same region corresponding to these hyperplanes), the answer would be $(1 - \frac{\theta}{\pi})^2 = 1 - \frac{2 \theta}{\pi} + \frac{\theta^2}{\pi^2}$, i.e. a bit larger. But already for $d = 3$ I couldn't find a closed-form expression for any particular (non-trivial) $\theta$.

Comment: Follow up on my earlier comment: in fact, you are asking about large deviations for quadratic forms, as follows: by Bayes', you are considering, with $A=\sum \eta_i g_i/\sqrt{\sum g_i^2 \sum \eta_i^2}$, the expression $$P(g_i>0,\eta_i>0,A\sim cos \theta)/P(g_i>0, A\sim \cos \theta).$$ Here, $g_i$ and $\eta_i$ are iid N(0,1).Computing the exponential rate of decay of both numerator and denominator then becomes a (tedious, but solvable) question on LDP for quadratic forms in i.i.d. random variables. I don't have time right now to fill in the details, hopefully someone else can follow up on that.

Comment: @TMM, I'm not sure they are different problems. If $A$ is the event of having angle in $[\theta-\epsilon,\theta+\epsilon]$ and $B$ is the event of both being in the positive orthant, then Bayes' Thm says that $P(A|B)/P(B|A)=P(A)/P(B)$. Since $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are easy, you can find $P(B|A)$ if you can find $P(A|B)$. Conditioning iid normals on being in the positive orthant is the same as using iid $|N(0,1)|$s, isn't it?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I've finally found the time to work out your suggested approach more closely, and I've added an answer below along the lines you suggested. I'm not sure this is the right approach though, so if you have further suggestions I'd be interested to hear them!

Comment: @oferzeitouni In the answer below I tried to compute the same probability but (as also pointed out by @Carlo) I may have messed up with the application of CLT when we are looking for probabilities in the tails. It seems you are familiar with large deviations theory and Cramer's theorem which might be the way to fix the argument. Could you take a look and see whether the approach can be made rigorous?

Comment: As a side remark, in dimension 1 and with arbitrary i.i.d. random variables, Cramer's theorem is true even without the condition $E(e^{tX_1})<\infty$ for all $t$. The large deviations for those are trivial in the exponential in N scale. However, you care about NORMALIZED sums. See the next comment.

Comment: The LDP approach can be made rigorous but not using Cramer's theorem directly (as you need to handle large deviations in $R^d$ for $d>1$). Note that  LD for normalized sums of squares of Gaussians can be derived (the derivation uses the Ellis-Gartner theorem, not Cramer's theorem) . Such computations have been performed in different contexts, see e.g. section 2.3 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4606.pdf. Your situation is very similar. Unfortunately, completing the details does require some time that I do not have right now.

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thanks for your comments earlier. This question got buried under other projects at the time, but coming back to it now I'd still be eager to find a solution. I've tried to follow up on your comments, but I miss a lot of background in large deviations theory to follow through and find an answer. Do you think you could take another look at it some time and see if you can find a solution (or point me towards specific methods/theorems that should be used here)?

Comment: I think my comment above and standard LD is all you need. Let me expand a bit. You are welcomed to contact me by email if needed.  Let's say you want to compute (see my comment above) $P(\eta_i>0,g_i>0, B)=P(B|\eta_i>0,g_i>0) 2^{-2n}$ where $B=\{|A-\cos \theta|<\epsilon\}$. Rewrite the conditional probability on the right as $Q(B)$, note that under $Q$ the $\eta$'s, $g$'s are still iid. Now on exponential scale, you have that $Q(B)\sim \max_{y,z} Q(\sum \eta_i g_i\sim y N,\sum \eta_i^2\sim z^2N,\sum g_i^2\sim y^2/ z^2 \cos(\theta)^2$

Comment: Now the latter probability is computed by the Gartner-Ellis theorem in $R^3$: the exponential rate is $I(y,z^2,y^2/z^2\cos(\theta)^2)$ where $I$ is the Legendre transform of $\Lambda(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)=\log E_Q(e^{\theta_1 \eta_1 g_1}\cdot e^{\theta_2 \eta_1^2} \cdot e^{\theta_3  g_1^2})$. This computation is an explicit, if tedious, two dimensional integral. One can numerically compute $\Lambda$, its Legendre transform, and then optimize over $z,y$ as  stated. For notation etc see my book with Dembo, in the section on Gartner-Ellis theorem.

Comment: @ofer Thanks for your comments, I really appreciate you taking your time for this. I'm still not quite sure how to continue, so I've sent you an e-mail with a few more questions. I'm sorry for taking up all your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Ofer Zeitouni](https://mathoverflow.net/users/35520/ofer-zeitouni), unless I made some serious mistakes somewhere in the calculations, I've been able to find the exact answer using large deviations theory. The derivation of the final result is a rather tedious affair, so I will just state the result here. Below $\mathcal{S}^{d-1}$ denotes (the uniform distribution over) the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The proof can be found in the appendix [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05760.pdf) and is about 5 pages long.

---

**Theorem:**
*Let $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y} \sim \mathcal{S}^{d-1}$, let $\phi(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$ denote the angle between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, and let
\begin{align}
f_d(\theta) = \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X} > 0 \ | \ \mathbf{Y} > 0, \ \phi(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}) = \theta).
\end{align}
For $\theta \in (0, \arccos \frac{2}{\pi})$ (respectively $\theta \in (\arccos \frac{2}{\pi}, \frac{\pi}{3})$), let $\beta_0 \in (1, \infty)$ (respectively $\beta_1 \in (1, \infty)$) be the unique solution to:
\begin{align}
\arccos\left(\frac{-1}{\beta_0}\right) = \frac{(\beta_0 - \cos \theta) \sqrt{\beta_0^2 - 1}}{\beta_0 (\beta_0 \cos \theta - 1)} \, , \qquad \arccos\left(\frac{1}{\beta_1}\right) = \frac{(\beta_1 + \cos \theta) \sqrt{\beta_1^2-1}}{\beta_1 (\beta_1 \cos \theta + 1)} \, . \label{eq:beta}
\end{align}
Then, for large $d$,
\begin{align}
f_d(\theta) = \begin{cases}
\left(\displaystyle\frac{(\beta_0 - \cos \theta)^2 }{\pi \beta_0 (\beta_0 \cos \theta - 1) \sin \theta}\right)^{d + o(d)}, & \qquad \text{if } \theta \in [0, \arccos \tfrac{2}{\pi}]; \\[3ex]
\left(\displaystyle\frac{(\beta_1 + \cos \theta)^2}{\pi \beta_1 (\beta_1 \cos \theta + 1) \sin \theta}\right)^{d + o(d)}, & \qquad \text{if } \theta \in [\arccos \tfrac{2}{\pi}, \tfrac{\pi}{3}]; \\[3ex]
\left(\displaystyle\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{\pi \sin \theta}\right)^{d + o(d)}, & \qquad \text{if } \theta \in [\tfrac{\pi}{3}, \tfrac{\pi}{2}); \\[3ex]
0, & \qquad \text{if } \theta \in [\tfrac{\pi}{2}, \pi].
\end{cases}
\end{align}*

---

To illustrate, the following figure shows $g(\theta) = \lim_{d\to \infty} f_d(\theta)^{1/d}$ against $\theta$. The constant $\alpha$ on the y-axis is $\alpha = \pi / (2 \sqrt{\pi^2 - 4}) \approx 0.648$. The dashed lines indicate the boundaries of the piece-wise parts in the theorem.

[image]

As stated in the OP, experiments suggested that $g(\arccos 0.9) \approx 0.8436$, and indeed from this theorem we find $g(\arccos 0.9)$ to be approximately $0.843$. This is quite different from Carlo's approximate solution based on Gaussians - if $\theta$ is close to $0$, the Gaussian approximation seems to be further off.

For the case $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$, the exact solution is $g(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi} \approx 0.5513$. Other answers based on different approximations all suggested $g(\frac{\pi}{3}) \in [0.55, 0.57]$ so here the Gaussian approximations are pretty accurate.

And as $\theta$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from below, we curiously get $g(\theta) \to \frac{1}{\pi}$. In other words, two almost-orthogonal vectors in high dimensions are in the same orthant with probability proportional to $(\frac{1}{\pi})^{d + o(d)}$. I'm not sure if there is a nice intuitive explanation for this.

Answer (score 5):

So I made this Gaussian approximation and find for $\theta=\pi/3$ a $d$-dependence of $f_d(\theta)$ that is well described by

$$f_d(\pi/3)\approx 2^{-d}e^{d/\pi^2}\Rightarrow g(\pi/3)\approx\tfrac{1}{2}e^{1/\pi^2}=0.553\;\;\;(1)$$

The plot shows the result of the Gaussian approximation (solid curve) and the asymptotic form (1) (dashed curve) on a log-normal scale, with a slope that matches quite well.

[image]

And here is the Gaussian approximation for several values of $\xi=\cos\theta$:

[image]

From the slope I estimate that

$$g(\theta)=\begin{cases}
0.66&\text{for}\;\cos\theta=0.9\\
0.63&\text{for}\;\cos\theta=0.75\\
0.55&\text{for}\;\cos\theta=0.5\\
0.41&\text{for}\;\cos\theta=0.25\\
0.25&\text{for}\;\cos\theta=0.1
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Gaussian approximation**

Denoting $\xi=\cos\theta$ we seek the probability

$$f_d(\xi)=2^d \frac{X_d(\xi)}{Y_d(\xi)},$$

as a ratio of the two expressions
\begin{align}
&X_d(\xi)=\int d\vec{x}\int d\vec{y}\,  \exp(-\tfrac{d}{2}\Sigma_n x_n^2) \exp(-\tfrac{d}{2}\Sigma_n y_n^2)\delta\left(\xi-\Sigma_n x_n y_n\right)\prod_{n=1}^d \Theta(x_n)\Theta(y_n),\\
&Y_d(\xi)=\int d\vec{x}\int d\vec{y}\, \exp(-\tfrac{d}{2}\Sigma_n x_n^2) \exp(-\tfrac{d}{2}\Sigma_n y_n^2)\delta\left(\xi-\Sigma_n x_n y_n\right)  .
 \end{align}
(The function $\Theta(x)$ is the unit step function.) Fourier transformation with respect to $\xi$,
\begin{align}
\hat{X}_d(\gamma)&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi\, e^{i\xi\gamma}X(\xi)\nonumber\\
&=\left[\int_{0}^\infty dx\int_{0}^\infty dy\,\exp\left(-\tfrac{d}{2}x^2-\tfrac{d}{2}y^2+ixy\gamma\right)\right]^d\nonumber\\
&=(d^2+\gamma^2)^{-d/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+i\,\text{arsinh}\,\frac{\gamma}{d}\right)^d,\\
\hat{Y}_d(\gamma)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi\, e^{i\xi\gamma}X(\xi)\nonumber\\
&=\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,\exp\left(-\tfrac{d}{2}x^2-\tfrac{d}{2}y^2+ixy\gamma\right)\right]^d\nonumber\\
&=(2\pi)^d(d^2+\gamma^2)^{-d/2}.
\end{align}
Inverse Fourier transformation gives for $\xi=1/2$ the solid line in the plot. The integrals are still rather cumbersome, so I have not obtained an exact expression for $g(\theta)$, but equation (1) shown as a dashed line seems to have pretty much the same slope.

---

**Addendum (December 2015)**

The answer of TMM raises the question, *"how can the Gaussian approximation produce two different results"*? Let me try to address this question here. To be precise, with "Gaussian approximation" I mean the approximation that replaces the individual components of the random $d$-dimensional unit vectors $v$ and $w$ by i.i.d. Gaussian variables with zero mean and variance $1/d$. It seems like a well-defined procedure, that should lead to a unique result for $g(\theta)$, and the question is why it apparently does not.

The issue I think is the following: The (second) calculation of TMM makes one additional approximation, beyond the Gaussian approximation for $v$ and $w$, which is that their inner product $v\cdot w$ has a Gaussian distribution,
$$P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{d (\alpha \pi - 2)^2}{2 \pi^2 - 8}\right).\qquad[*]$$
The justification would be that this additional approximation becomes exact for $d\gg 1$, by the central-limit-theorem, but I do not think this applies, for the following reason: The approximation [*]
breaks down in the tails of the distribution, when $|\alpha-2/\pi|\gg 1/\sqrt d$. So in the large-$d$ limit it only applies when $\alpha\rightarrow 2/\pi$, but in particular not for $\alpha\ll 1$.

Comment: $f$ above is already conditioned on $w > 0$ so I suppose your result would then be that $f \sim 2^{-d} e^{-d/\pi^2} \approx (0.553)^d$. That sounds about right, judging from experimental data; thanks! If you could work out the details for general $\theta \in (0, \frac{1}{2} \pi)$ that would be great, but I understand is that's too much to ask.

Comment: clear enough, thanks! I have corrected for the conditioning on $w>0$ and added results for the Gaussian approximation for other values of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! One last question: could you provide a bit more information on how you generated those curves and estimated the slope? Did you also use the Gaussian approximation for that, with different $\xi$? I would like to get (approximations of) some more values of $g(\theta)$ but I'm not sure how to compute those numbers from the given expressions, even with mathematical software.

Comment: Here are the lines of Mathematica code that generate the plot (in Gaussian approximation) for a chosen value of $\xi$; I just fitted a straight line to get the slope: numerator[d_,gamma_]:=(d^2 + gamma^2)^(-d/2) * (Pi/2 + I * ArcSinh[gamma/d])^d; denominator[d_,gamma_]:=(d^2 + gamma^2)^(-d/2) * (2 * Pi)^d; xi=1/2; Plot[Log[2^d*Re[NIntegrate[Exp[-I * xi * gamma] * numerator[d,gamma],{gamma,-Infinity, Infinity}]]/NIntegrate[Exp[-I * xi * gamma] * denominator[d,gamma],{gamma,-Infinity,Infinity}]], {d,5,30}]

Comment: Just a note: I've removed the "accepted"-mark as I'm not convinced anymore that this is *the* correct answer. See below for a different approach leading to a different answer. It is still a very useful and interesting answer showing an approach I had not considered, but it may not solve the problem.

Comment: I think you are right w.r.t. the CLT application being wrong for $\alpha \neq 2/\pi$. That also explains why in the alternative approach you see the results are the same only if $\alpha \approx 0$, as there the CLT was used for a RV with mean $0$. I actually thought about what you said before and realized that the CLT would not be accurate, and then I went home from work and forgot about it... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Again thank you very much for your answer, and I am convinced it is the most accurate answer so far. For my research question I'd be interested to find a somewhat accurate expression for all $f(\theta)$ (or $g(\theta)$) in the interval $(0, \pi/2)$, but I am not able to generalize/reproduce your results for arbitrary $\theta$, as I am not familiar enough with Fourier transforms. Could you expand how (analytically or numerically) you obtained those values for $g(\theta)$ for different $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\expn}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\varn}{\operatorname{Var}}$
Following up on Brendan McKay's approach in the comments, let $v, w$ be two uniformly random vectors on the sphere. We are interested in the following probability:
\begin{align}
p = P(v > 0 | w > 0, v \cdot w = \alpha) = \frac{P(v, w > 0 | v \cdot w = \alpha)}{P(w > 0 | v \cdot w = \alpha)} = 2^d P(v, w > 0 | v \cdot w = \alpha).
\end{align}
Here we used that the events $\{w > 0\}$ and $\{v \cdot w = \alpha\}$ are pairwise independent. Bayes' law states that 
\begin{align}
P(v, w > 0 | v \cdot w = \alpha) = \frac{P(v, w > 0)}{P(v \cdot w = \alpha)} \, P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0).
\end{align} 
Since clearly $P(v > 0) = P(w > 0) = 2^{-d}$, and $\{v > 0\}$, $\{w > 0\}$, $\{v \cdot w = \alpha\}$ are pairwise independent events, this is equal to 
\begin{align}
p &= \frac{2^d P(v, w > 0)}{P(v \cdot w = \alpha)} \, P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0) = \frac{P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)}{2^d P(v \cdot w = \alpha)}.
\end{align}
Note that for two vectors on the sphere, the density $P(v \cdot w = \alpha)$ is well-known to be proportional to $\sin(\arccos \alpha)^d = (1 - \alpha^2)^{d/2}$ by computing the volume of the corresponding spherical cap.

For computing $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$, we use a Gaussian approximation: a $d$-dimensional vector $v$ or $w$ on the unit sphere (in the positive orthant) roughly follows the same distribution as sampling a $d$-dimensional vector where each entry is drawn from a(n absolute) Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{d}$. This is the approximation which makes the end result possibly incorrect.

So, for computing $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$, we basically want to compute the density of inner products between $v$ and $w$ at $\alpha$, given that both $v$ and $w$ are sampled from an absolute Gaussian distribution $|N(0,\frac{1}{d})|^d$ (also known as the half-normal distribution). The inner product is described by $S = \sum_{i=1}^d V_i W_i$ where the $2d$ random variables $V_i, W_i \sim |N(0, \frac{1}{d})|$ are all independent, and as each product $X_i = V_i W_i$ follows the same distribution (and is independent from other values $X_j$), by the CLT the sum $S$ of these $d$ i.i.d.\ random variables is approximately normally distributed with a certain mean and variance. As $\expn(V_i) = \expn(W_i) = \sqrt{2/(\pi d)}$ and $\expn(V_i^2) = \expn(W_i^2) = \frac{1}{d}$, for $S$ we obtain the following expectation 
\begin{align}
\expn(S) = d \cdot \expn(V_i W_i) = d \cdot \expn(V_i) \cdot \expn(W_i) = \frac{2}{\pi}.
\end{align}
Similarly, for the variance we get
\begin{align}
\varn(S) = d \cdot \left[\expn(V_i^2 W_i^2) - \expn(V_i W_i)^2\right] &= \frac{1}{d} \left(1 - \frac{4}{\pi^2}\right).
\end{align}
As a result, the probability $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$ roughly corresponds to the density of a Gaussian random variable $Z$ with mean $2/\pi$ and variance $(1 - 4/\pi^2) / d$ at the point $\alpha$. This density is equal to
\begin{align}
P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0) \approx P\left(N\left(\frac{2}{\pi}, \frac{1}{d} - \frac{4}{\pi^2 d}\right) = \alpha\right) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{(\alpha - \frac{2}{\pi})^2}{\frac{2}{d} (1 - \frac{4}{\pi^2})}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{d (\alpha \pi - 2)^2}{2 \pi^2 - 8}\right).
\end{align}

To summarize, by using exact arguments for $P(v \cdot w = \alpha)$ (i.e.\ not using a Gaussian approximation), and using approximate arguments for $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$, we obtain the end result:
\begin{align}
\boxed{\ p \approx \exp\left[d \left(- \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2} \ln(1 - \alpha^2) - \frac{(\alpha \pi - 2)^2}{2 \pi^2 - 8} \right) + o(d)\right].}
\end{align}
Substituting $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, this results in 
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \approx \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \, \exp\left(-\frac{(\pi -4)^2}{8 \pi^2 - 32}\right) \approx {\color{blue}{0.5684}}.
\end{align}

### Alternative approach

By also using a Gaussian approximation for the density $P(v \cdot w = \alpha)$, instead of using exact arguments there we can follow a similar path as for the probability $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$ by approximating the spherical vectors with Gaussian vectors, and invoking the CLT to approximate the probabilities in the limit for large $d$. Similar computations show that in that case the inner product has mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{d}$, and so the probability $P(v \cdot w = \alpha)$ can be estimated as
\begin{align}
P(v \cdot w = \alpha) \approx P\left(N\left(0, \tfrac{1}{d}\right) = \alpha\right) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha^2 d}{2}\right).
\end{align}
In that case, using a Gaussian approximation for both densities, we obtain the approximation
\begin{align}
\boxed{\ p \approx \exp\left[d \left(- \ln 2 + \frac{\alpha^2}{2} - \frac{(\alpha \pi - 2)^2}{2 \pi^2 - 8} \right) + o(d)\right].}
\end{align}
Substituting $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ here, we obtain
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \approx \frac{1}{2} \, \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi - 5}{2 \pi^2 - 8}\right) \approx {\color{blue}{0.5578}}.
\end{align}

Concluding, together with Carlo's result, this gives three different answers (all Gaussian approximations) to the same question of computing $g(\pi/3)$. It is not clear which of them is correct, or whether they are perhaps all wrong...

---

**Update**: Now community wiki -- please feel free to update the answer with correct arguments, not using the CLT.

---

### Using large deviations

Instead of using the CLT for $P(v \cdot w = \alpha | v, w > 0)$, let us use Cramer's theorem. Let $S = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d \tilde{V}_i \tilde{W}_i$ 
be the sum over the products of normalized half-normal random variables $\tilde{V}_i, \tilde{W}_i \sim |N(0,1)|$. Then as computed above, for 
$X_i = \tilde{V}_i \tilde{W}_i$ we have $\expn(X_i) = 2/\pi$ and $\varn(X_i) = 1 - 4/\pi^2$. With some effort we can further compute the MGF of $X_1$ as
\begin{align}
\expn(e^{t X_1}) &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(\tfrac{-v^2 - w^2}{2} + t v w) \ dv \, dw = \frac{\pi + 2 \arcsin t}{\pi \sqrt{1 - t^2}}.
\end{align}
This last expression is conditioned on $t < 1$, as otherwise the integral does not converge. Using Cramer's theorem, we have that $P(S > \alpha)$ is 
proportional to $\exp(-d I(\alpha))$ where $I(z)$ is the function
\begin{align}
I(z) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}} \left[t z - \ln \expn(e^{t X_1})\right].
\end{align}
Substituting the above, this is equal to
\begin{align}
I(z) = \sup_{t \in (0,1)} \left[t z - \ln \left(\frac{\pi + 2 \arcsin t}{\pi \sqrt{1 - t^2}}\right)\right].
\end{align}
The function of $t$ on the right is decreasing on $(0,\frac{2}{\pi})$ so the supremum is attained at $t \to 0^+$, in which case the limit is also $0$. This leads
to $I(z) = 0$ and so 
\begin{align}
P(v \cdot w > \alpha | v, w > 0) &\sim \exp(-d \cdot 0) = 1.
\end{align}
The problem in this derivation is that Cramer's theorem only applies when $\expn(e^{t X_1}) < \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$ which is not the case here. So this first try does not work.

Comment: Perhaps some of the approximations can be made rigorous using the Berry-Eseen theorem?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I think the problem is that the normal approximation for spherical vectors is just not tight; whether it is used in both expressions, or only in one of them, or as in Carlo's answer, it is just wrong to replace the uniform distribution on the sphere by a multivariate Gaussian distribution. In that sense I do not think the CLT-part is the problem, but the part that each coordinate is normally distributed, and strengthening the CLT-part only strengthens a wrong result.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Maybe a simulation could suggest which of the three answers (if any) is correct.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay The numbers are so close ($0.553, 0.558, 0.568$) that simulations are not going to be very convincing; you need many simulations to get such a precision. Also these are limits for large $n$, so any finite simulation will not produce the correct value anyway.

Comment: from your $-\ln(1-\alpha^2)$ and $\alpha^2$ terms, it is clear that the Gaussian approximation needs small $\alpha$; you could try a simulation for $\alpha=0.1$; the difference is then quite large between the two answers (0.25 versus 0.39), that should be visible.

Comment: @Carlo: The problem is that for small $\alpha$ also the probability that two vectors are in the same orthant is small. In dimension $10$, if I do $10^6$ experiments with $v$ and $w$ at angle $\arccos 0.1$, I find that they are in the same orthant $0$ out of those $10^6$ times.

Comment: @Carlo: See the edit to the question, with simulations for *large* $\alpha$. Perhaps all answers are better approximations for small $\alpha$, but it surprises me how far off they are from reality when $\cos \theta = 0.9$.

Comment: excuse me, but I'm a bit confused by your request in the latest edit: you ask for a derivation that does not use the CLT, but isn't that just the content of the first answer?

Comment: @Carlo You use a different approach, which may or may not be equivalent to this answer without the CLT (it's not obvious to me if it will be the same), and which does not provide a general formula for arbitrary $\alpha$. I'm looking to see if this answer can be extended to a full and more correct answer not using the CLT, but using large deviations theory. Note that your answer uses a Gaussian approximation for both probabilities (similar to the "alternative approach" above) while the first approach above only uses a GA for one of them, which might be more precise.